# assertThatThrownBy() check field on custom exception

Tags: java, exception, assertj

How can I check particular field value in my custom excepiton using assertJ?

Here is exception class:

```
public class SomeException extends RuntimeException {
    private final Set<Integer> something;

    public SomeException (String message, Set<Integer> something) {
        super(message);

        this.something = something;
    }

    public Set<Integer> getSomething() {
        return something;
    }
}
```

Here is my test:

```
    assertThatThrownBy(() -> service.doSomething())
        .isInstanceOf(SomeException.class)
        .hasMessageStartingWith("SomeException has 1,2,3,4 in something field. I want assert that")
        . ??? check that SomeException.getSomething() has 1,2,3,4 ???
```

The problem is that if I chain **extracting()** it will think I'm using **Throwable**. So I can't extract *field* something

**Update:**

```
SomeException throwable = (SomeException) catchThrowable(() -> service.doSomething(

assertThat(throwable)
    .hasMessageStartingWith("extracting() bellow still think we're working with Throwable")
    .extracting(SomeException::getSomething <<<--- doesn't work here)
```

I have tried following, as suggested bellow:

```
 assertThat(throwable)
        .hasMessageStartingWith("Works except containsExactlyInAnyOrder()")
        .asInstanceOf(InstanceOfAssertFactories.type(SomeException.class))
        .extracting(SomeException::getSomething)
        .->>>containsExactlyInAnyOrder<<<--- Not working!!!
```

But I can't use *containsExactlyInAnyOrder*() anymore :(

Please advise

Comment: You can catch the `Throwable` using `catchThrowable` and then make whatever assertions you want to on that (after casting to your type if necessary).

Comment: Nice idea, unfortunately even if I hard cast  SomeException  throwable = (SomeException ) catchThrowable(() ... extracting() method doesn't take into account fields of SomeException

Comment: I have updated casting example

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are quite a few variations on `extracting`, the one you want to use is [`extracting(String)`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.18.0/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#extracting(java.lang.String)), ex:

```java
   assertThatThrownBy(() -> service.doSomething())
        .isInstanceOf(SomeException.class)
        .hasMessageStartingWith("SomeException ... ")
        .extracting("something")
        .isEqualTo(1,2,3,4);
```

Use [`extracting(String, InstanceOfAssertFactory)`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.18.0/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#extracting(java.lang.String,org.assertj.core.api.InstanceOfAssertFactory)) to get specialized assertions, so if the value is a collection you can try:

```java
   assertThatThrownBy(() -> service.doSomething())
        .isInstanceOf(SomeException.class)
        .hasMessageStartingWith("SomeException ... ")
        .extracting("something", InstanceOfAssertFactories.ITERABLE)
        .contains();
```

You can also try: [`hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.18.0/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object))

**Update:** working example

```java
SomeException throwable = new SomeException("foo", Sets.newSet(1, 2, 3, 4));

assertThat(throwable).hasMessageStartingWith("fo")
                     .extracting("something", InstanceOfAssertFactories.ITERABLE)
                     .containsExactly(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: this is close, but there is no such an overloaded method with InstanceOfAssertFactories.ITERABLE :(  any ideas how can I cast first example (extracting("something")) to iterable type?

Comment: I have also tried casting throwable to my custom exception type as proposed in comment to my question, but exctracting() still things I'm working with Throwable instead of custom type. Please advise

Comment: tiillias I did not suggest to use `asInstanceOf` and you did not try the `extracting` I pointed out, I have updated my answer with some working code.

Comment: many thanks -> I have tried it and as I mentioned I don't have extracting() which accepts such a parameter. I have checked it once again and it seems I have to update library to the newest version. Unfortunately it will be very difficult, cause I have to update spring-boot dependencies then etc. I will mark it as answer, unfortunately I can't use it because of my version of assertj :(

Comment: yes, please make sure that version of assertJ needed for your code to work is specified in answer. Otherwise it will raise the same question in future

Comment: It is usually ok to use the latest, 3.18.0 at the time of this reply

Comment: @tillias assuming you have a maven project and you are at least on java 8, you can add <assertj.version>3.18.0</assertj.version> in your properties section to get the updated artifact without upgrading the spring-boot-dependencies version. It should work with both Spring Boot 1.5.x and 2.x.

Answer (score 26):

It looks like you're looking for `catchThrowableOfType`, which allows you to receive the correct class:

```java
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.catchThrowableOfType;

SomeException throwable = catchThrowableOfType(() -> service.doSomething(), SomeException.class);

assertThat(throwable.getSomething()).isNotNull();
```

Comment: great advice, nice and clear way to handle it in unit tests

Comment: This should be the best and accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like :

```
assertThatThrownBy(() -> service.doSomething())
    .isInstanceOf(SomeException.class)
    .hasMessageStartingWith("SomeException occurred")
    .isEqualToComparingFieldByField(
        new SomeException("", Sets.newHashSet(1,2,3,4)));
```

This way you don't have to worry about changing the field name in future because you're not hardcoding it anywhere in the assert statements.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the `extracting` method would be to catch the exception in `matches` or `satisfies` method :

```java
var elements = Set.of(1, 2, 3, 4);

assertThat(throwable)
  .isInstanceOf(SomeException.class)
  .hasMessageStartingWith("...")
  .matches(e -> ((SomeException) e).getSomething().containsAll(elements);
```

```java
assertThat(throwable)
  .isInstanceOf(SomeException.class)
  .hasMessageStartingWith("...")
  .satisfies(e -> {
    SomethingException somethingException = (SomethingException) e;

    assertThat(somethingException.getSomething()).contains(1, 2, 3, 4);
  });
```